# Android Studio: classes of new added project are not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I added new project (which i named WearShared) to my project Wear through 'File-New-New module...'
Then added some classes in this added WearShared project. But these classes
are not seen in my Wear project (the problem is shown on screenshot below). How to fix this? Some ideas, please, which I could try.
Thank you very much!

:Wear project build.gradle:

```
...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
    compile project(':WatchShared')
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `RequestHandlerListener` marked as `public`?

Comment: yes, marked as public

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `include ':WatchShared'` on your `settings.gradle` and clean & rebuild your project.

If you are on windows, [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81190) sometimes prevents the project from properly rebuild, so you could try to manually delete the `build` directories when making a `gradle clean`

Comment: Thank you, Logain, for your reply. But on including new module to project Studio adds the included module (project) to settings.gradle in include. So I already have this in my settings.gradle added (with Studio)

Comment: Oh, you are right, I don't usually use that option and forgot it. Just in case, it never harms to make a clean & rebuild. Specially if you are on windows, since sometimes it doesn't properly remove the generated files.

Comment: i've removed 'build' folder and made 'gradlew clean'. it didn't help. i decided to remove and reinstall Studio, removed ..gradle' and 'Android Studio 1.4' folders